# Showing correct date from API

Tags: javascript, date

I'm getting crazy with showing a date correctly to the client:

From the API I receive `data.expiry_date` and its value is: `2017-09-06T23:59:59Z`

The client to show that data looks like this:

```
var date = new Date(data.expiry_date);
$('#expiry_date').val(`${date.getDate()}/${date.getMonth() + 1}/${date.getFullYear()}`);
```

The result is a day before than expected: it should be **06/09/2017** but it show **07/09/2017**.

Basically the `date` value from the action `var date = new Date(data.expiry_date);` is: `Thu Sep 07 2017 01:59:59 GMT+0200 (CEST)`.

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Sorry, a typo while copy / pasting logs. I corrected my question. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: If you just want to display the date as 07/09/2017, just reformat the string. There's no need to parse it to a Date then format it, that's just way more work than is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You're not in the same time zone. 
`2017-09-06T23:59:59Z` is UTC
which is same as 
`Thu Sep 07 2017 01:59:59 GMT+0200 (CEST)`

Comment: And how can I show the correct date to all users? All other expiry dates are ok, this one has one day less... it should display 07/09/2017 independently by the time zone...

Comment: @AyeyeBrazo It does not have one day less/more, It has two hours less/more because you are running 2 hours ahead of UTC. It is the correct date/time.